# model can be saved,but id is nil in rails3 with oracle-enhanced adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

```
ruby 1.9.2 
rails 3.0.0 
ruby-oci 2.0.4
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter 1.3.1
```

for example
table named users(id:number(38,0), name)

```
user = User.new
user.name ='test'
user.save! # is successful
user.id # got nil
user.name # got 'test'
```

and in the database I have sequence named "USERS_SEQ" and worked well(nextval or currentval is right)

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your table does not have primary key constraint and therefore primary key column is not identified by oracle_enhanced adapter?

See discussion at http://groups.google.com/group/oracle-enhanced/browse_thread/thread/3cf18b86333752c5

Comment: As a work-around for views, materialized views - add a PK constraint (yes it's possible). `ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW XYZ ADD CONSTRAINT PK_X PRIMARY KEY (something) DISABLE NOVALIDATE`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explicitly assign the users_seq.nextval to user.id. This is not done automatically like in SQL Server. The is no such thing as a auto increment column in Oracle.

Comment: It will auto execute users_seq.nextval and generate right insert sql

Comment: apparently not. Maybe you should give us some more info. Like the class definition. You have to enforce the table name, pk and sequence in the model's definition